# Load An Image From A Relative Path in SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

Im playing around with SFML and C++ and have one question, when loading a texture, you must specify its directory like so:

```
sf::Texture myTexture;
if(!(myTexture.loadFromFile("C:\\Folder\\image.png")));
```

But when distributing my game how will i be sure that the user will download the game onto the same drive, and image.png may be on the E: drive instead of the C: drive. I want to know a way to locate an image file in C++ without having to specif its directory. Here is theoretical code

```
if(!(myTexture.loadFromFile(@"image.png")));
```

so now no matter where this image is located my game can find the image. My only concern is that someone might already have a file called image.png on there computer so for this i would give the image files very abstract and unique names, to prevent duplication.

Comment: Relative paths is what you need

Comment: Or /usr/share/yourapp is what you need, one just might not be able to find it on windows, but probably windows has some default locations to store data for all users as well. this might be of help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2010/03/18/where-should-i-store-my-data-and-configuration-files-if-i-target-multiple-os-versions.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading images (and sounds, fonts etc) from a relative path works as well.

If you are concerned about potential filename collisions, distribute your game with a folder containing all your assets. For example `yourGame_resources`, placed at the same level as your executable. Load by

```
myTexture.loadFromFile("yourGame_resources/image.png")
```